# What is the legal status of travelling with (unprescribed) methadone in your carry-on?

Tags: canada, hand-luggage, ireland, drugs

My girlfriend and her sister will be going to Canada for two weeks at the start of July. They both use drugs recreationally and aren't open with their family and are quite isolated.

My girlfriends sister has obtained methadone from a friend and wants to know the legality of travelling with it

Her only issue is that it would be confiscated if she packs it in carry-on luggage due to the 100ml 3.4 fluid ounce limit however I'm a bit shocked that they aren't more concerned about the legal status. My girlfriend won't travel with her sister if she brings it because she's worried it might be illegal.

The sister doesn't have a prescription for it and AFAIK, I told her that methadone is a controlled substance in nearly every country and so carrying it across an international border without any good reason is like smuggling heroin. She'll certainly faces prison time and/or hefty fines.

But I'm not sure, I have a few friends who borrowed opiate pills from their relatives in the States and brought them over to Ireland and they weren't stopped.

Will it be an issue or not?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge from Ireland

Comment: Your first reaction sounds correct to me. "They weren't stopped" does not mean they _wouldn't_ have been in pretty deep trouble if they _were_ stopped or otherwise found out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about smuggling. Travel.SE does not provide assistance with breaking the law.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: The question just asks whether it is legal.  A perfectly good answer would be "No it isn't" and I'm in the process of writing such an answer.  The question doesn't ask how to get away with it.

Comment: @RobertColumbia The question isn't asking for assistance breaking the law. It's asking for confirmation that something is illegal and the context is one of not approving of that act ("I told her that [it's illegal]", "My girlfriend won't travel with her sister if she brings it because she's worried it might be illegal").

Comment: Methadone is a ["Schedule I"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_Drugs_and_Substances_Act#Schedule_I) controlled substance, in the same class as cocaine, methamphetamine, heroin, ketamine and amphetamines. There is no distinction in law between these examples and unprescribed methadone. She might as well be taking cocaine or heroin through the border in the eyes of the law. It would be reckless in the extreme.

Comment: An additional concern: even if the methadone were prescribed, it would likely cause the suspicion (valid, in this case) that the people carrying it are users of illegal drugs...which is a reason to be denied entry. I'd recommend pre-researching the availability of methadone clinics in the major cities which are planned for the visit. However, if they brought the results of this search into Canada, in a form that could be found in a search of their baggage or phone, it could also result in being turned away.

Comment: Don’t go to Singapore or you may have a hangman problem to solve.

Comment: Make your girlfriend's sister watch "Bangkok Hilton", especially the episode where a mentally disabled kid who had no idea he was involved in drug trafficking gets executed. Because drug trafficking is exactly what she's planning to do.

Comment: More importantly, it's already illegal in Ireland, being a class A drug and any amount is worth 6 months in prison (life, in case of intent to supply). So, arriving in Canada isn't even the first problem.

Comment: Also [Brokedown Palace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-xXGVsYOyM)... and I wasn't allowed to say this in my answer, but drugs have been known to drive users to all sorts of deception and manipulation; it wouldn't be a surprise if the drugs got snuck into the other person's bag.  (the drug user reasons "Can't get drugs if I'm in jail, and not getting drugs is not an option").

Comment: I think your girlfriend had best change her plans. Sister is on the way down and the only way out is to hit bottom and survive. Not a good plan to be around her because there is going to be a lot of pain and collateral damage before it's all through.

Comment: Let me put it in perspective. If you are hit by a car in your way for the airport, get hospitalized for two weeks and need many months of physical therapy to get a full recovery, compared with the girls tried to smuggle illegal narcotics into enter Canda you are a lucky guy

Comment: Carrying illegal drugs across an international border is insanity.

Answer (score 76):

### It is not legal to bring methadone into Canada without a prescription.

Methadone is a controlled drug in Canada under the [Controlled Drugs and Substances Act](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-38.8/FullText.html) (it's in Schedule I, number 5 (4)).  It is illegal to import a controlled drug into Canada without authorization (section 6, "Importing and Exporting").  The maximum punishment is life imprisonment; I suspect in practice the punishment would be less, but I don't know how much.  It probably wouldn't be good.

There is an [exemption](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/health-concerns/controlled-substances-precursor-chemicals/policy-regulations/policy-documents/section-56-class-exemption-travellers-who-importing-exporting-prescription-drug-products-containing-narcotic-controlled-drug.html) that can apply for prescription medications for a traveler's own use, but since the drug was not legally prescribed to your girlfriend or her sister, the exemption does not apply.

If they declare the drugs at Customs, the drugs will certainly be confiscated, and they may or may not be punished.  If they don't declare them, their luggage may be randomly searched, and if caught they will almost certainly be punished.

Comment: I'm not sure if drug dogs search out Methadone, but that seems like a *huge* risk to me.

Comment: Note that even if it's not considered "trafficking", mere unauthorized possession of a Schedule I controlled substance still attracts up to seven years in jail per 4 (1) and (3). Doesn't sound worth betting that the drug dogs won't pay attention.

Comment: The punishment will be *much* less.  "Life imprisonment" is intended for people organizing the smuggling of multiple shipments of tons of drugs - not for people bringing it in for their own recreational use.

Comment: @MartinBonner I wouldn't count on that.  People with minor charges have ended up with huge sentences because they wouldn't testify against a supplier.

Answer (score 19):

*I am going to assume you want to advise them on the correct and legal behavior, not help them circumvent the rules.*

First, medications are exempt from the 100ml rule and everyone advises you keep your meds in carryon. (For example, here's the [advice](https://travel.gc.ca/travelling/health-safety/medication) for Canadian travellers.) It should have a label that identifies it. I have never been asked to show a doctor letter or other paperwork for prescription meds, but in theory you should have this too. If the label identifies it as medication, being over 100 ml should not be an issue. Of course if it is in some sort of unlabeled container, there is going to be problem with that. This will apply when leaving Ireland, clearing security to get on the plane. I suppose if it says something on the label that gets the agent's attention, they could call the local police, but their focus is really on making sure nobody blows up the plane.

Second, while many people put all sorts of things in their checked luggage without consequence, this doesn't mean that there is no problem bringing things into countries where they are controlled. There are xrays and such that are on arrival to look for things like drugs in people's bags. There are sniffer dogs in the arrivals area, and trained border agents who send people to secondary for more inspection. If this methadone had been prescribed to your friend, then bringing it would be ok if

> The drug must be for your use or for the use of a person who is travelling with you and for whom you are responsible. The drug must be in hospital or pharmacy-dispensed packaging, the original retail packaging, or have the original label attached to it clearly indicating what the health product is and what it contains.

(A quote from the link above.)

If it's just in some sort of jam jar with no label, there's going to be a problem. Smuggling opiates is non trivial. Hoping to get away with it is not a strategy. If the friends are unable to get any methadone prescribed to them, and unable to function without it, then the trip is a bad idea.

Comment: I can easily believe that they don't check prescriptions for a wide range of medication. But I bet it would be the first thing they asked for if somebody came to the border with methadone.

Comment: *"I have never been asked to show a doctor letter or other paperwork for prescription meds"* Have you ever tried to cross a border while carrying drugs that can be used recreationally? I wouldn't be surprised to find that they're fairly uninterested in stuff like antibiotics or whatever, but are much more cautious when dealing with things like opiates.

Comment: I have taken pseudoephedrine into New Zealand. It is banned there, and I was told it required a letter, which I got, but on arrival no-one was interested in the letter.

Comment: @KateGregory pseudoephedrine isn't banned in NZ, but it is a Class B controlled substance.  NZ has a much higher risk from domestic meth farms than they do from importation these days - when you rent a property, there is typically a meth test done on the property and the results made available, its that rife here.

Answer (score 18):

There are a whole string of violations here.

- **Failure to Declare** the medication.  It is a crime to fail to declare *anything* on a long list of things you need to declare, and you bet medicine is at the top of that list.  The only way out of that one is to declare "Yes, I have methadone in my bag".  Otherwise if you're caught, it's big trouble, a big fine, and you will not be visiting Canada anymore. But if you admit to having it, you evade that charge but not these:
- **Possession of methadone without a prescription**. That itself is a crime even if  they were not crossing an international border.
- **Importing drugs into Canada**. Obviously, trying to import narcotics into Canada is a serious felony, so they will get to be the guests of the RCMP for a number of **years**,  and will not successfully visit any other countries for the rest of their lives, because they'll be in all the databases as a convicted felon.

And your girlfriend will be neck deep in this if she is connected with the friend at all.  And she will be connected with the friend because *young people can't stop using social media*, and will be shown to be fully cognizant of the plot (and thus an accomplice).  **The texts will be found. This SE post will be found. Everything will be found**. Cops are very good at police forensics, young people are very bad at it, and drug use doesn't help. International authorities tend to regard friends traveling together as mutually culpable.

Also it is possible for drug users to entangle other people into their schemes.

Your girlfriend's best bet is to either not go, or find a pretense to travel separately. Both ways.

Your best bet is making sure not to travel with them.

Comment: Opioid Use Disorder is in the DSM. It is a diagnosable mental illness. For all it's faults, the inclusion in the DSM is the best heuristic we have as to whether or not something is a mental illness or not. I'm not a doctor but I've spent an awful lot of time with doctors and in facilities dedicated to treating things of this exact nature.

Comment: My many years' experience practicing criminal law supports @Harper's original word choices: drug users are a lot more...um... _flexible_ with their truth-telling than non-users, and much more likely to manipulate others to serve their own ends. His advice is spot-on.

Comment: Do you have a cite that the sentence for bring a small quantity of methadone (not enough to trade) is likely to be result in a sentence of *years*?  I also expect that most countries cannot view Canada's database of convictions, so it may well have no impact of future travel.

Comment: @MartinBonner *Are you proposing to lie* to other countries' IO's in the future when they ask you "ever been convicted of a crime" or "ever been refused entry"? (Pretty sure if you are caught smuggling, jailed then deported, that's a refusal). As linked in comments, methadone is Schedule I.

Comment: @Willeke Well-cleaned. If medicine has intervened because a person's life is being ruined, I believe the purpose of the DSM is to provide reporting codes for that.  Not declare all instances of that behavior to be mental illness. *But that's a point on which I can agree to disagree*.